# Transit from Dulles to Falls Church

Tags: airport-transfer, washington-dc, iad

Going to DC for a family vacation and arriving into Dulles. Any input on getting from Dulles to the Falls Church area that does not include an expensive cab ride?

Comment: You don't specify where in Falls Church, but since it's inside the Beltway, I'd take a look at *[How to get to/from Dulles airport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/how-to-get-to-from-dulles-airport)*

Comment: Take the Silver Line Express to the Metro station, and then the silver line to West Falls Church or East Falls Church stations.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, this can be an answer. The canonical answer says the Silver Line does not extend to Dulles.

Comment: The Dulles Metro station does not open until (IIRC) 2017, although you can see construction now. The Silver Line Express bus will take you to the closest station *now in operation.*