# How to get from Washington Dulles Airport to Edgewood Conference Centre?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, itineraries, washington-dc, iad

[image]

I'm traveling from Washington Dulles Airport to Edgewood Ramada conference centre with a suitcase etc. and don't want to take an expensive taxi to get there. Any options?

Comment: Is there a closer airport you can fly into? BWI is a littler closer, but not by much...

Comment: I don't want to be rude... but for a specific point to point journey by public transport with no particular special needs... [travel.se] might not be the best site. Are there any options? [Yes, there are loads](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Dulles+International+Airport,+1+Saarinen+Cir,+Dulles,+VA+20166,+USA/Ramada+Edgewood+Hotel+and+Conference+Center,+1700+Van+Bibber+Rd,+Edgewood,+MD+21040,+USA/)

Comment: Related: *[How to get to/from Washington Dulles International Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8887)* All public transportation to the Baltimore area from Dulles will go through Washington, all of the options for which are given in that question. Frankly,  I would rent a car. It will take several hours and a minimum of four different modes (bus, Metro, commuter rail, taxi/TNC) to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

1. Take the Silver Line Express bus from the Airport to Wiehle-Reston East
2. Take the Metro Silver line to Metro Center
3. Take the Metro Red line to Union Station
4. Take the MARC commuter train to Edgewood
5. Take a taxi to the conference centre (3 miles/5 km)

Comment: Call me stupid, but...is this a set of options, or a sequence? (I guess the latter, but still...)

Comment: This is really the only option, but my goodness the travel from IAD to Edgewood might be longer than the flight itself. 1 hour from Wiehle to Union Station and then another hour to 1.5 hours depending on which MARC train. OP definitely picked the wrong airport for arrival

Comment: @motoDrizzt Sequence

Comment: @ethorn10 Yeah, BWI would've been the best bet I think (might be wrong as I'm not from there)

Comment: In hindsight I think I definitely chose the wrong airport as BWI would have been easier to travel to Edgewood from. I know my options now for next time!